# Passing image into an SQL 2008 Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, image, sql-server-2008

I have deploy my code in visual studio .NET 2010 in order to select images and save them into a SQL server (remote) 2008 express

When i deploy my tables as: [dbo].[tablename] then at the last command of my code which is:

sqlFile = New SqlFileStream(filePathName, fileToken, FileAccess.Write)

I receive the error of 'Access denied'

When i deploy my tables as : [UserSchema].[tablename] then i receive the error of:

**'The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you'**

I have made all the changes that i know around of SQL Server but nothing.

Please noticed that i can write data in all the privious tables without any problem, My issue starts only when i'm trying to pass the image into the shell of the table

Is there anyone which have faced this problem before?

Comment: Apologies if this is totally unrelated to your issue, but maybe using a binary field is a good alternative? Maybe you're already doing this, it's not clear to me from reading your question.

Comment: Dear Nick 

I want to thank you very mcuh for your interest to reply in may issue

I'm using streaming method to write the image on the table because it takes smaller amount of space on the table

And of course the field on which i'm trying to write the image accepts only binary format data

I have put a sniffer on my PC in order to discover wether the error comes from the SQL it self or from the Windows Domain controler.

So i see that this issue is not so clear, because i catch the following lines on the sniffer:

Comment: * From 10.93.1.29  to 10.93.1.10 SMB Trans2 Request, QUERY_PATH_INFO, Query File Basic Info, Path: \v1\RemoteDB\SRU\tPImages\tPImages_Image\A7286747-7755-4CC3-9736-AFF7AF8DF8DF\9eb85e3fce4b48cfa92a831c335df9b7


* From 10.93.1.10  to 10.93.1.29 SMB Trans2 Response, QUERY_PATH_INFO, Error: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED


* From 10.93.1.29 to 10.93.1.10 SMB NT Trans Request, NT CREATE


* From 10.93.1.10 to 10.93.1.29 SMB NT Trans Response, NT CREATE, FID: 0x0000, Error: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED


Please noticed that: my PC is the IP 10.93.1.29 and my server is the IP 10.93.1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are about 20+ reasons why an access  is denied for a request to SQL SERVER
Have look at this article from Miscrosoft.

- [Potential causes of the "SQL Server 
  does not exist or access denied"

  error message](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=328306)

Most common errors are as follow

- Not specifying proper connection
  string
- The local security policy user rights
  assignment for your Application are
  not enough

Hope it helps

Comment: Well dear asad butt

I solve the problem related to my above question 

the problem was that i have to put 

trusted security = true

on the database connection 

and on the server connection as well 

any way i thank you very much for your interest

Comment: Glad it was over, bit related to second type!